# Git clone returns "error: invalid path 'public/C:\Users\My-PC\Documents\Projects\Sample\storage\logs/laravel.log'"

Tags: php, laravel, windows, git, macos

I get this error message on clone (I have windows, my colleague is working on mac machine):

```
error: invalid path 'public/C:\Users\My-PC\Documents\Projects\Sample\storage\logs/laravel.log'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

and when I try the suggestion, I get this:

```
>git restore --source=HEAD :/
error: invalid path 'public/C:\Users\My-PC\Documents\Projects\Sample\storage\logs/laravel.log'
```

my colleague has no issues, but I can't pass this error on clone

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the cause, since my colleague pushes to git, some Mac files were pushed that caused issues on my end and they should not be inside git like .DS_Store files and .idea directory

[image]

**Removing them from git (1) & adding them to gitignore (2) fixed the problem for me Alhamdulillah!**

Answer (score 1):

Check first what `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` returns

If there is nay file with an actual path `public/C:\Users` in there, then indeed, that would not be a valid path, and would therefore block any `git restore` attempt.

Check if you ca remove it:

```
git mv public/C:\Users\My-PC\Documents\Projects\Sample\storage\logs/laravel.log \
  public\Sample\storage\logs\laravel
```

Or remove it

```
git rm --cached public/C:\Users\My-PC\Documents\Projects\Sample\storage\logs/laravel.log
```