# Git - fatal: unable to checkout working tree

Tags: laravel, git

I uploaded my Laravel project to a shared server, now I am trying to clone the project from a local computer and I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid path 'public/C:\xampp\htdocs\pfuxelacolab\storage\logs/laravel.log'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Help Please...

Comment: can you show us the git status?

Comment: pfuxelaco@pfuxela.co.mz [~/public_html/team]# git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Did you upload the install using FTP?

Comment: No, using Cpanel-File Manager

Comment: Make sure the (global) gitignore of everyone pushing to the repository is complete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759541/git-clone-returns-error-invalid-path-public-c-users-my-pc-documents-projects

Comment: If you use git/composer, you should install the application with git and composer, not with the file manager.

Comment: Can you share the clone command you did ? `/` and `\\` in a path is strange

Answer (score 1):

You have a repository with a commit that you, personally, cannot use on your system.  A Linux user can use this commit, but you can't.

The problem here is the file's name:

```
public/C:\xampp\htdocs\pfuxelacolab\storage\logs/laravel.log
```

In a Git commit,<sup>1</sup> there are no folders: files simply have long names like this one.  Each *forward* slash `/` in a committed file's name—and *only* the forward slashes—will, on a Windows system, be turned into the appropriate backwards slash `\` and Git will break up the path into pieces such as `public` and `laravel.log` and so on.<sup>2</sup>  Git will then do what your OS demands: treat each of the various pieces as folder-and-file parts, and make any folders needed so that it can create *your OS's idea of a file* named `laravel.log` in *your OS's idea of a folder*.  Git itself doesn't hold with such silly notions: you just have a file with a long name with forward slashes in it, but OSes have these dumb and silly folder-and-file requirements, so, okay, Git will deal with it.

In any case, this file's name includes `C:` right in the middle—not up front, where some DOS/Windows software *might* be able to deal with it, but in the middle, after `public`.  So Git is trying to create a new folder, named either `C:` or `C:\xampp\htdocs\pfuxelacolab\storage\logs`, within a `public` folder, and that is never going to work: Windows says you can't do that.  Linux, by contrast, says *Oh you'd like to create that as a folder name?  Sure, done!*

So, someone on a Linux or similar system can check out this commit.  Having done so, they can *fix the file's name* or *remove the file entirely* and make a new commit that doesn't have this bizarro name with the colon and backslashes inside it.  Remember, *Git* demands *forward* slashes.  It will make forward slashes for its own commits, from the OS's folders and files.  But it will also take any file names with embedded colons and backslashes found on a Linux system, and make a commit from those, that can't be extracted on a Windows system.  That's what someone did: they created a folder named `C:\xampp\htdocs\pfuxelacolab\storage\logs` in a folder named `public`, and created a file named `laravel.log` in that, and then added that to Git's index and committed it, presumably on a Linux system.<sup>3</sup>

The *easiest* way for you to deal with this will be to boot up a Linux system (perhaps in a VM) and check out the commit in question and make a corrected one to use instead.  Whether you can do this at all in WSL, I have no idea.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, this claim is true not of the commits themselves, but of Git's *index*.  But commits move "through" the index on the way out to your working tree, and are made *from* the index, so the condition applies anyway.

<sup>2</sup>Since I don't use Windows, I don't know whether Git will try to break apart the backslashed pieces here too—but it won't matter because of the `C:` part.  It would be interesting to create a file named `test\path/file` on a Linux system, commit it, and try to check that commit out on Windows, though.  Does Windows Git make a `test` folder?  If not, does it (whether intentionally or merely accidentally) *use* an *existing* `test` folder and make a `path` folder?  But Windows forbids colons in path names, and the embedded `C:` part, with or without any subsequent part, is the first and fatal problem here.

<sup>3</sup>While I keep saying "Linux" here, any OS that allows this will suffice, so Solaris or one of the BSDs would do the trick too.  You could even do this on macOS.